# Should an undergraduate applying for academic internships switch to a multi-page CV from a one-page resume?

Tags: cv

I am an undergraduate student applying for internships that are frequently in academia.

Currently, I've been providing all my experience in a one-page resume format, and find myself having to continue to make the text font size smaller and smaller.

Would it be best for me to switch to a CV?

Comment: Don't make the fonts smaller... :)

Comment: Good answer from Michael.  Ask yourself how you would make a one-minute pitch in an elevator, to convince someone you should be considered for your dream job.  Make sure the things you selected for the elevator are clearly visible in your CV, and do a little pruning.  There are people you can ask for help with this.

Answer (score 3):

CV's are used more for people who have more [experience in academia](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/curricula-vitae-cvs-versus-resumes/) - as it includes publications, awards, grants, etc. As someone who is still an undergraduate student, I can't imagine that your resume should be more than 1 page - [usually it is 1 page per 10 years of experience](https://www.monster.com/career-advice/article/how-to-decide-on-resume-length). I would suggest going through your resume and take out bullet points that could be considered "fluff". Stuff like "demonstrated leadership" and "increase efficiency within the department" do not show any actual accomplishments. However, it would not be a bad idea to have a CV on hand. As you probably know, resumes should be tailored specifically to each job, so I would highly recommend that you keep a master resume that details all your accomplishments at each job, and maybe have the "fluff" in there, but when you apply for a job, make a copy of that resume and tailor it specifically to the job.

Comment: I disagree that the "one page for ten years" rule is applicable to *academic* CVs.  My impression is that an academic CV should contain a complete list of relevant experience and accomplishments, and be as many pages as necessary.